# High CPU usage running webassembly based WebGL program

Tags: webgl, webassembly, emscripten

I am making a game using webassembly (C++ and emscripten), where I am using OpenGL to generate graphics. I have noticed that my game often uses a lot of CPU, typically 200-300%. This CPU usage becomes higher if I have a larger 3D model or if my shader is more complicated.

Is this normal for webassembly? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm bit worried that I made a mistake since normally I would not expect the CPU usage to be directly linked to the size of 3D models (I would expect that to mostly take a toll on the graphics card), but since it is webassembly it might be different.

Are there any good tips for trying to reduce CPU usage when running OpenGL and webassembly?

Edit:
The basic example I started working from was
https://github.com/timhutton/opengl-canvas-wasm
live demo here (https://timhutton.github.io/opengl-canvas-wasm/)
This already runs at quite high CPU. What is wrong with that example making it run at such high CPU load? It is not the `glBufferData`, even removing that keeps the CPU high.

Comment: Maybe your browser uses a software rendering fallback?

Comment: Can't possibly tell you what you're doing wrong without code but [here's a webassembly webgl app using opengl](https://greggman.github.io/better-unity-webgl-template/). If it's not performing bad then the issue is your code. If you're using 20yr old fixed function opengl (glVertex) then that would be run reason for bad perf.

Comment: No I dont use old opengl function rendering. The example you linked performs well, but so does my app if my number of vertices is low. I started developing from this example:
https://github.com/timhutton/opengl-canvas-wasm
Also, if I directly take that example and increase the number of vertices to 10000+, my CPU also goes up, so does not seem like it's due to any changes I did

Comment: "Maybe your browser uses a software rendering fallback?"

Is it possible to check this somehow?

Comment: Yeah so I just noticed that the simple example also has a live demo here: https://timhutton.github.io/opengl-canvas-wasm/
which already runs at 50% CPU for me, so maybe there is something inherently wrong with that example? I edited the post to add more details

Comment: check chrome://gpu or about:gpu depending on what browser you're using

Comment: wow, that was it! chrome://gpu indeed said that hardware acceleration was not being used, I had to go to settings and activate "use hardware acceleration when available". Thanks a ton, I find it quite strange that this answer was not easily found by just googling this issue, I can not be the first one to stumble on this. Anyway, If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser may use software rendering for some reason, check your browsers GPU debugging page to see if there's anything wrong, in Chrome that is `chrome://gpu`, in Firefox it's the GPU section in `about:support`.